# Python 3 script that passes each member of an array to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a small python 3 utility script that checks to see if a file exists on my server.

So I have the code below that has a big array of string values that I pass to a simple function that returns the url and the response code.

However, when I run it I get all these errors I don't even know where to start:

```
$ python ReturnPath.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "ReturnPath.py", line 86, in <module>
  checkResponse(u)
 File "ReturnPath.py", line 5, in checkResponse
    code = urllib.request.urlopen(url).getcode()
 File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 328, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
 File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 354, in full_url
    self._parse()
 File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 383, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url) 
ValueError: unknown url type: '"https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/ae275ecb-183e-4e8d-8465-9d6d36c1323f.jpg"'
```

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request


def checkResponse(url):
    code = urllib.request.urlopen(url).getcode()
    print(url + " = " + code)
    return

arrCases = []

arrCases.extend([
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/ae275ecb-183e-4e8d-8465-9d6d36c1323f.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/3ea92fa3-1ef0-4358-b38d-bb04e653aa53.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/7958a0e3-171b-46b5-875e-970368389bdf.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/e9a6cb00-6811-4b47-9aac-88480578dd44.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/73df88c3-b829-4519-9523-2bbe1f2c8549.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/61aa614b-5c95-487c-b4e3-783231b43677.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/8be7811f-18dc-4a81-a557-8b81605e3452.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/56539acb-2b1b-4410-a4bc-ac2eb0dc00fa.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/8bcf93fc-b435-4fd4-9c82-4aba78c58529.jpg",
])

for u in arrCases:
    checkResponse(u)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe http instead of https ?

Comment: I tried to clean up the traceback but it was a mess, please review.

Comment: No if I run urllib.request.urlopen().getcode() on the urls separately, they all work

Comment: The traceback indicates that you have double quotes (sic) around the value: Invalid URL `'"string"'`. The code you have posted does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, extending the array instead of just declaring it is weird.

Comment: @tripleee well I was trying to add them with only one append

Comment: @Xukrao The traceback would suggest Python 3.7...

Comment: `arrCases = ["one", "two", "three]` would still be more elegant as well as clearer and easier to type.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate. I get a file not found when I execute that code in 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to catch errors from broken URLs. I also increased speed through `multiprocessing.Pool`.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError, URLError
import multiprocessing

def checkResponse(url):
    try:
        code = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=1).getcode()
    except (HTTPError, URLError) as error:
        print(url, " = ", error)       
    else:
        print(url, " = ", code)

    return

arrCases = []

arrCases.extend([
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsNOB.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/ae275ecb-183e-4e8d-8465-9d6d36c1323f.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/3ea92fa3-1ef0-4358-b38d-bb04e653aa53.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/7958a0e3-171b-46b5-875e-970368389bdf.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/e9a6cb00-6811-4b47-9aac-88480578dd44.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/73df88c3-b829-4519-9523-2bbe1f2c8549.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/61aa614b-5c95-487c-b4e3-783231b43677.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/8be7811f-18dc-4a81-a557-8b81605e3452.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/56539acb-2b1b-4410-a4bc-ac2eb0dc00fa.jpg",
    "https://myserver.org/Media/CharacterAvatarImages/8bcf93fc-b435-4fd4-9c82-4aba78c58529.jpg",
])

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    pool.map(checkResponse, arrCases)
```

Comment: That's all very nice, but that doesn't attempt to solve the bug in the question (which apparently doesn't exist in the code the OP actually posted anyhow).

Comment: No, maybe this can also help; though as already mentioned, the changes you made are all unrelated to the problem the OP is asking about. Strictly speaking, this could be flagged as "not an answer", but I don't think anybody wants to do that. Perhaps you should explain your changes, though; code-only answers sometimes attract downvotes because it's not clear why something was changed.

Comment: And of course, spending time on answering a question which is eligible for closing as unlear and/or unreproducible is a risk investment.