# How to fix "urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using "urilib.request",but faild,here are error message:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe "E:/python project/practice.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python project/practice.py", line 2, in <module>
    urlrequest.urlopen('https://www.baidu.com')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 548, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1387, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

see the following code

```
import urllib.request as urlrequest
urlrequest.urlopen('https://www.baidu.com')
```

I try to install pyopenssl

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

But system remind me:it's already exist

- My os is Window
- Python edition:3.7
- IDE:Pycharm

Comment: Maybe this example can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54716184/10418812